# Multiprocessing in python - processes not closing after completing

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I have a Process pool in python that is starting processes as normal, however, I have just realized that these processes are not closed after the completion (I know that they completed as the last statement is a file write).
Below the code, with an example function ppp:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import itertools

def ppp(element):
    window,day = element
    print(window,day)
    time.sleep(10)

if __name__ == '__main__':  ##The line marked
    print('START')
    start_time = current_milli_time()
    days = ['0808', '0810', '0812', '0813', '0814', '0817', '0818', '0827']
    windows = [1000,2000,3000,4000,5000,10000,15000, 20000,30000,60000,120000,180000]
    processes_args = list(itertools.product(windows, days))        
    pool = Pool(8) 
    results = pool.map(ppp, processes_args)
    pool.close() 
    pool.join() 
    print('END', current_milli_time()-start_time)
```

I am working on Linux, Ubuntu 16.04. Everything was working fine before I added the line marked in the example. I am wondering if that behavior can be related to the missing of a return statement. Anyway, that is what looks like my 'htop':
[image]
As you can see, no process is closed, but all have completed their work.

I found that related question: [Python Multiprocessing pool.close() and join() does not close processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53062355/python-multiprocessing-pool-close-and-join-does-not-close-processes), however, I have not understood if the solution to this problem is to use map_async instead of map.

EDIT: real function code:

```
def process_day(element):
    window,day = element
    noise = 0.2
    print('Processing day:', day,', window:', window)
    individual_files = glob.glob('datan/'+day+'/*[0-9].csv')
    individual = readDataset(individual_files)
    label_time = individual.loc[(individual['LABEL_O'] != -2) | (individual['LABEL_F'] != -2), 'TIME']
    label_time = list(np.unique(list(label_time)))
    individual = individual[individual['TIME'].isin(label_time)]
    #Saving IDs for further processing
    individual['ID'] = individual['COLLAR']
    #Time variable in seconds for aggregation and merging
    individual['TIME_S'] = individual['TIME'].copy()
    noise_x = np.random.normal(0,noise,len(individual))
    noise_y = np.random.normal(0,noise,len(individual))
    noise_z = np.random.normal(0,noise,len(individual))
    individual['X_AXIS'] = individual['X_AXIS'] + noise_x
    individual['Y_AXIS'] = individual['Y_AXIS'] + noise_y
    individual['Z_AXIS'] = individual['Z_AXIS'] + noise_z
    #Time syncronization (applying milliseconds for time series processing)
    print('Time syncronization:')
    with progressbar.ProgressBar(max_value=len(individual.groupby('ID'))) as bar:
        for baboon,df_baboon in individual.groupby('ID'):
            times = list(df_baboon['TIME'].values)
            d = Counter(times)
            result = []
            for timestamp in np.unique(times):
                for i in range(0,d[timestamp]):
                    result.append(str(timestamp+i*1000/d[timestamp]))
            individual.loc[individual['ID'] == baboon,'TIME'] = result
            bar.update(1)

    #Time series process
    ts_process = time_series_processing(window, 'TIME_S', individual, 'COLLAR', ['COLLAR', 'TIME', 'X_AXIS','Y_AXIS','Z_AXIS'])
    #Aggregation and tsfresh
    ts_process.do_process()
    individual = ts_process.get_processed_dataframe()
    individual.to_csv('noise2/processed_data/'+str(window)+'/agg/'+str(day)+'.csv', index = False)
    #NEtwork inference process
    ni = network_inference_process(individual, 'TIME_S_mean')
    #Inference
    ni.do_process()
    final = ni.get_processed_dataframe()
    final.to_csv('noise2/processed_data/'+str(window)+'/net/'+str(day)+'.csv', index = False)
    #Saving not aggregated ground truth
    ground_truth = final[['ID_mean', 'TIME_S_mean', 'LABEL_O_values', 'LABEL_F_values']].copy()
    #Neighbor features process
    neighbors_features_f = ni.get_neighbor_features(final, 'TIME_S_mean', 'ID_mean')
    neighbors_features_f = neighbors_features_f.drop(['LABEL_O_values_n', 'LABEL_F_values_n'], axis=1)
    neighbors_features_f.to_csv('noise2/processed_data/'+str(window)+'/net/'+str(day)+'_neigh.csv', index = False)
    # Final features dataframe
    final_neigh = pd.merge(final, neighbors_features_f,  how='left', left_on=['TIME_S_mean','ID_mean'], right_on = ['TIME_S_mean_n','BABOON_NODE_n'])
    final_neigh.to_csv('noise2/processed_data/'+str(window)+'/complete/'+str(day)+'.csv', index = False)
    return
```

So as you can see, the last statement is a write to file, and it is executed by all the processes, I do not actually think that the problem is inside this function.

Comment: It looks like the script that you're running isn't exiting (on your HPC cluster?) and your example doesn't reproduce the problem. As a general rule, `mp.Pool` doesn't play well with job schedulers like slurm. I can't give you any specific advice without more information.

Comment: Which information should I provide you? Unfortunately, I cannot post the entire code, the thing to which I want to push the focus is that without the `marked line` everything works fine. @CJ59

Comment: Well the marked line doesn't do anything in the context of your example. So take it out? I'd bet it doesn't work fine though, it just fails more quietly. Are you running this through a job scheduler? If it's off the command line, how do you know it completes work?

Comment: The last statement of each process    is the creation of a csv. Regarding the marked line, if I remove it everything is fine on Linux, but windows requires it for compatibility. No job scheduler, it the first time ever I get this behavior from the server.

Comment: You're probably blocking on `pool.map()` so you should double check all your files are there and there aren't any hanging file handles. You could also replace `.join()` with `.terminate()`, but it shouldn't matter. Make sure you're clearing all the old processes and output files before you run it again. It looks like you have a lot of stale processes in that list.

Comment: So all the files are created correctly and there are no more statements after it, should I exit the processes?

Comment: As Guido has said, your code here looks fine and isn’t showing the same problem. The line you’ve highlighted shouldn’t affect the outcome on either platform. Your mapped function is somehow not completing.

Comment: I added the real code, however, I think that this will generate more confusion instead of solving the problem, but thank you.